# pytorch model returns NANs after first round

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

This is my first time writing a Pytorch-based CNN.  I've finally gotten the code to run to the point of producing output for the first data batch, but on the second batch produces `nan`s.  I greatly simplified the model for debugging purposes, but it's still not working right.  The model shown here is just a few fully connected layers with a linear output.

I am guessing that the problem is the the back-propagation step, but it's unclear to me where and why.

Here is a very simplified version of the model that still produces the error:

### Data loader:

```py
batch_size = 36
device = 'cuda'
# note "rollaxis" to move channel from last to first dimension
# X_train is n input images x 70 width x 70 height x 3 channels
# Y_train is n doubles
torch_train = utils.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(np.rollaxis(X_train, 3, 1)).float(), torch.from_numpy(Y_train).float())
train_loader = utils.DataLoader(torch_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

### Define and create the model:

```py
def MyCNN(**kwargs):
    return MyCNN_model_simple(**kwargs)

# switched from Sequential() style to assist debugging
class MyCNN_model_simple(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyCNN_model_simple, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = FullyConnected( 3 * 70 * 70, 100)
        self.fc2 = FullyConnected( 100, 100)
        self.last = nn.Linear(100, 1)
#         self.net = nn.Sequential(
#             self.fc1,
#             self.fc2,
#             self.last,
#             nn.Flatten()
#         )
    def forward(self, x):
        print(f"x shape A: {x.shape}")
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        print(f"x shape B: {x.shape}")
        x = self.fc1(x)
        print(f"x shape C: {x.shape}")
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print(f"x shape D: {x.shape}")
        x = self.last(x)
        print(f"x shape E: {x.shape}")
        x = torch.flatten(x)
        print(f"x shape F: {x.shape}")
        return x
#        return self.net(x)

class FullyConnected(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, dropout=None):
        super(FullyConnected, self).__init__()       
        layers = []
        layers.append(nn.Linear(in_channels, out_channels, bias=True))
        layers.append(nn.ReLU())
        if dropout != None:
            layers.append(nn.Dropout(p=dropout)) 
        self.net = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)

model = MyCNN()
# convert to 16-bit half-precision to save memory
model.half()
model.to(torch.device('cuda'))
```

### Run the model:

```py
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
dev = torch.device('cuda')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, weight_decay=1e-4)
losses = []
max_batches = 2

def process_batch():
    inputs = images.half().to(dev)
    values = scores.half().to(dev)
    
    # clear accumulated gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # make predictions
    outputs = model(inputs)
    # calculate and save the loss
    model_out = torch.flatten(outputs)
    print(f"Outputs: {model_out}")
    loss = loss_fn(model_out.half(), torch.flatten(values))
    losses.append( loss.item() )
    # backpropogate the loss
    loss.backward()
    # adjust parameters to computed gradients
    optimizer.step()


model.train()
i = 0
for images, scores in train_loader:
    process_batch()
    i += 1
    if i > max_batches: break
```

### Stdout:

```
x shape A: torch.Size([36, 3, 70, 70])
x shape B: torch.Size([36, 9800])
x shape C: torch.Size([36, 100])
x shape D: torch.Size([36, 100])
x shape E: torch.Size([36, 1])
x shape F: torch.Size([36])
Outputs: tensor([0.0406, 0.0367, 0.0446, 0.0529, 0.0406, 0.0391, 0.0397, 0.0391, 0.0415,
        0.0443, 0.0410, 0.0406, 0.0349, 0.0396, 0.0368, 0.0401, 0.0343, 0.0419,
        0.0428, 0.0385, 0.0345, 0.0431, 0.0287, 0.0328, 0.0309, 0.0416, 0.0473,
        0.0352, 0.0422, 0.0375, 0.0428, 0.0345, 0.0368, 0.0319, 0.0365, 0.0382],
       device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16, grad_fn=<AsStridedBackward>)

x shape A: torch.Size([36, 3, 70, 70])
x shape B: torch.Size([36, 9800])
x shape C: torch.Size([36, 100])
x shape D: torch.Size([36, 100])
x shape E: torch.Size([36, 1])
x shape F: torch.Size([36])
Outputs: tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16, grad_fn=<AsStridedBackward>)

x shape A: torch.Size([36, 3, 70, 70])
x shape B: torch.Size([36, 9800])
x shape C: torch.Size([36, 100])
x shape D: torch.Size([36, 100])
x shape E: torch.Size([36, 1])
x shape F: torch.Size([36])
Outputs: tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16, grad_fn=<AsStridedBackward>)
```

You can see the `nan`s that are coming out of the model starting with the second batch.  Is there anything obviously wrong that I'm doing?  If anyone has tips on best practices for debugging pytorch module runs that I can use to track down the problem, that would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: PyTorch's [detect_anomaly](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.detect_anomaly) can be helpful for determining when `nans` are created. I would consider not using `.half()` until after you've got your network running with normal full-precision.

Comment: Thanks, will test that out.  I resorted to `.half()`s due to GPU memory issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch to full precision when updating the gradients and to half precision upon training

```
loss.backward()
model.float() # add this here
optimizer.step()
```

Switch back to half precission

```
for images, scores in train_loader:
    model.half()  # add this here
    process_batch()
```